# One job at time with multiple workers

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

Trying this

```
Redis::funnel('TestJob')->limit(1)->then(function () {

    // Processing
    // ...
    
    usleep(1000000 / 5); // distribute evenly 5 items per second

});
```

It works fine while one worker is running.
But if more than one worker then there are errors like this

```
{"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Redis\\LimiterTimeoutException(code: 0):
        at /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Limiters/ConcurrencyLimiter.php:76)
```